# Grails 3 - f:table - how to display property of related class

Tags: grails, web, field

There is 2 simple classes:

```
class Entity{
Integer id
Status status
String type
}

class Status{
Integer id
String name
}
```

I just need to replace representation of "status" field  in Entity list and edit - instead of my.appStage : 1 -> "normal"
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named `_displayWrapper.gsp` in the following directory:

```
/views/entity/status
```

Then in the file add the following:

```
${value.name}
```

Assuming you just want to print the text 'normal'.

There are other ways to achieve this, see [docs](http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html).

Update after question:

For `f:all` you could add `_wrapper.gsp` to the directory mentioned above and add the following:

```
<div class="fieldcontain required">
    <label for="status">Status</label>
    <g:select name="status" from="${Status.all}" optionValue="name" optionKey="id" value="${entity?.status}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike
Now it's clear for f:table, but what about f:all?
Documentation is not useful.

Comment: Error evaluating expression [Status.all] on line [3]: Cannot get property 'all' on null object

Comment: I don't know your package names, you'll have to import them

Comment: from="${my.app.Status.all}" - now it works, thanks!

Anyway, better docs will be useful

Comment: Agree, you have to dig around in code a bit to find out what gsp template to add, not ideal