# How to change what grails puts into dropdown in f:all

Tags: grails3

I have a very simple project with users have accounts and accounts have transactions.

I generated the views, controllers and services using grails generate-all Transaction.

Transaction domain object looks like this:

```
class Transaction {
    Account account
    BigDecimal debit = 0
    BigDecimal credit = 0
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The controller only has this:

```
def create() {
    respond new Transaction(params)
}
```

I.e. only sends a new transaction (not a list of accounts).

However, the create UI has a dropdown of all accounts in the system (not just for this user):

[image]

The question is, is there a way to "fix"  to only show the users accounts?  If not, I can always manually write the create view with each field hard coded.  Just wondered if there was a cool grails way to do it.

See https://github.com/nutmix/grails-dropdow-air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question, isn't it? After investigating the solution to this question for a while, I found we could accomplish the need by doing as described below.

In `create` view of `transaction`, customise a bit of how to render data:

```
<g:form resource="${this.transaction}" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="form">
         <f:field bean="transaction" property="account" wrapper="transaction/account"/>
         <f:all bean="transaction" except="account"/>
    </fieldset>
...
            </g:form>
```

where `wrapper` is the directories (i.e. path) where we place `_wrapper.gsp`. Read more about [Loading Templates Conventionally Example](https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html) section to know how and where you define customised wrapper, template and widget. To solve your problem, `_wrapper.gsp` has the following codes:

```
<%@ page import="dropdown.Account" %>
<%
    def values = dropdown.Account.all.collect {it.currencyIso}.unique(true)
    //println values
%>
<div class="fieldcontain required">
    <label for="account">Account <span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
    <g:select name="account" from="${values}"
              value="${transaction?.account}"/>
</div>
```

The location of `_wrapper.gsp` is `grails-app/views/_fields/transaction/account/_wrapper.gsp`.

The result looks like the following screenshot.
[image]

P/S: I got this idea when I came across [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984084/865603) about `f:table`.